# Java: How to compare a string to a return from toString()

Tags: java, string, class

Basically when I try to compare a class to a string using .equals it returns false all the time.

For example:

myClass.java

```
public String toString()
{
    return "Apple";
}
```

main.java

```
System.out.println(myClass.equals("Apple"));
```

Will print "false".

What should I use to compare myClass with a string?

Comment: `myClass.toString().equals("Apple")`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare? name of class or something?
Please elaborate by example, which case is true and which case is false.

Comment: Overwrite method `toString()` and `equals()` then use equal() for compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the definition form the Object class :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "Apple";
}
```

and then compare

```
System.out.println(myClass.toString().equals("Apple"));
```

where `myClass` shall be an instance of `MyClass` using the [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should call toString, not class directly.

```
myClass mc= new myClass();
if(mc.toString().equals("Apple"){

}
```

BTW, Java class names starts with Capitals. For ex. `MyClass`

Comment: My actual class does start with a captial, this was just a hastily typed example (sorry).

And this works thanks! Do you know why I need to do this, but if I print the class, it will print "Apple"?

Comment: When you print, it automatically calls .toString() but not in other places.

Answer (score 1):

you could actually implement equals -

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if(object instanceof String) {
        return ((String)object).equals(mName);
    }
    return false;
}
```

mName is a member of your class that contains its name.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption that toString would be automatically called was wrong.

For anyone else wondering:

```
System.out.println(myClass.toString().equals("Apple"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way... works for me fine..

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "Address: " + address+ ", streetName=" + stName ;
    }
```